# Why can't I run conda command even though it is slready installed in the machine?

Tags: datascience-anaconda

```
user_name@server_name:~/bbq_spatial$ pip show conda
Name: conda
Version: 4.3.16
Summary: OS-agnostic, system-level binary package manager.
Home-page: https://github.com/conda/conda
Author: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
Author-email: conda@continuum.io
License: BSD
Location: /home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: pycosat, requests, ruamel.yaml
Required-by:
user_name@server_name:~/bbq_spatial$ conda update conda
conda: command not found
user_name@server_name:~/bbq_spatial$
```

Why can't I run conda command even though it is slready installed in the machine?

How can I run conda command?

EDIT:

> Add the output of command -v pip and command -v conda to the question. – Nasir Riley

```
user_name@server_name:~$ command -v pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
user_name@server_name:~$ command -v conda
user_name@server_name:~$ command -v conda
user_name@server_name:~$
```

Comment: Add the output of `command -v pip` and `command -v conda` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

What you have installed is the `conda` Python module that you'd import in a Python shell like any other module.

If you want the `conda` binary that's used as an application, then you need install install Anaconda or Miniconda which you can get from the following sites:

https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution#Downloads

https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

There are instructions on those sites and Google for installing either one if you need help.